# How to structure different components within cell, rows and sections?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios-autolayout

I am trying to understand how to structure different components within rows and sections. So my question are

1.would the top view,imageview and the components under it be separate cell or a single cell within a section.

2.What if one section does not have a imageview or a certain component. Would we just hide that view or would it be in a separate cell and that wont be called. And if hiding is the solution, how would you remove the space.

I am looking for just an abstract answer nothing specific. Just to understand how to structure views in tableviews

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You pull all in one cell. For hiding any view (image, button, etc),

1. Put top content, image and comments on stack view.
2. Whenever there is  no image, use imageView.hidden = true
3. Image space should automatically disappear.

Refer to [this link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2198310-uistackview-tutorial-for-ios-introducing-stack-views) for more elaborate tutorial

Answer (score 1):

1. It depends on the preference of the developer. If you want a more flexible and easy to update/adjust view you can create a separate cell/nib file for that view. Additionally you can create it on one cell only but be careful because updating of design/view/content won't be easy.
2. If the imageview does not have a value I suggest that you always put a placeholder for that imageview so that the user will know that the image is not fetched.